# How will notifyAll work in this scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is the small snippet of multi-threaded queue I wrote,

```
synchronized void add(int i) {
    if (count == size) {
        System.out.println("******full***");
        isQueueFull = true;
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("adding number: " + i);
    val[end++] = i;
    count++;
    if (isQueueEmpty) {
        isQueueEmpty = false;
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}



synchronized int remove() {
    if (count == 0) {
        isQueueEmpty = true;
        System.out.println("******empty***");
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    int t = val[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < end - 1; i++) {
        val[i] = val[i + 1];
    }
    val[end - 1] = -1;
    end--;
    count--;

    if (isQueueFull) {
        isQueueFull = false;
        this.notifyAll();
    }
    System.out.println("removing number: " + t);
    return t;

}
```

Lets say I have four threads adding to the queue and one thread removing from the queue. At one point,say array get full and I call wait on all four threads adding to the queue.

Now when an element gets removed, I need to call notifyAll on all of the sleeping threads.(It is giving me an arrayOutofBound exception)  My questions is this, what is the flow of threads like in case of notifyAll.

Since add is synchronized method, there can only be one thread execution in it. But because of wait, we have now four threading sleeping inside it. So on notifyAll, will all four threads still be inside the add method(despite it being a synchronized method) and execute? or will it done one by one sequentially, with all of the threads being locked until one thread is completed.

It is very difficult for me to debug it in eclipse.  I have a work around for arrayOutOfBoundException by putting a return statement after wait, but I would still like to understand the flow in case of notifyAll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting is very different from sleeping. The [javadoc of `wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) explains it:

> The thread **releases ownership of this monitor** and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. **The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor** and resumes execution.

(emphasis mine)

BTW, it also contains a strong rule that you're not respecting:

> As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and **this method should always be used in a loop**:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

So, when `notifyAll()` is called, the 4 threads compete to get back the monitor. Each one gets it back once the previous one has released it, and continues executing.

Comment: just to clarirfy, I am calling add and remove in a loop itself.

Comment: And that doesn't change anything. Your consumer thread should keep waiting **while** the queue is empty. The producer thread should keep waiting **while** the queue is full. With your code, as soon as one of the consumer threads removes one element from the queue, the 4 producer threads stop waiting and start adding their element to the queue. Even if notifyAll() is never called, if a spurious wakeup happens as the doc indicates, the producer thread can leave its waiting state and add its element to the queue although it's still full.

Comment: If I am not wrong, that is causing the arrayIndexOutOfBound exception? So to fix the error, I intend to add a return statement after wait in producer along with notifyAll in consumer and vice versa. That does not crash but is that design correct?

Comment: @Dude, "I intend to add a return statement after wait".  It doesn't make sense to wait, and then give up.  For example: if your `remove()` method can fail when there's nothing to remove, then it might as well fail _immediately_ instead of waiting.  On the other hand, if it's going to wait, then it might as well keep waiting until there is something in the queue for it to take.

Comment: @Dude, It probably also does not make sense to use `notifyAll()` in this scenario.  If you've got N threads waiting on an empty queue, and some other thread adds _one_ item to the queue, then there's no point in waking up more than one of the waiting threads (`notify()` just wakes one).

Comment: @jameslarge: using notifyAll() is safer. If another thread waits on the same lock to do something other than producing values, then you have a deadlock. notifyAll() is simpler: everyone is woken up, checks if the condition to restart is fulfilled, and goes back to sleep if it isn't.

Comment: `notifyAll()` is safer if you don't understand what you're doing.  `notify()` can be much more performant if you do understand.  Brian Goetz explains when to use `notify()` in section 14.2.4 of _Java Concurrency in Practice_.  Basically:  It's safe to call `notify()` when every thread that waits is waiting for the same condition; and it makes sense to call `notify()` when the action of the notifying thread only enables one waiting thread to proceed.  The classic _unsafe_ use of `notify()` is a blocking queue where _one_ lock object is used for wait/notify by both producers _and_ consumers.

Comment: That's basically what I said in my previous comment. Just wanted to point out that if your primary concern is maintainability, and ease of evolution, or if you plan to wait on the same lock for another reason than producing values, then notifyAll is a better choice. If your primary concern is performance, and you know that only producers wait on this lock, and there is only one consumer, then notify() is the best choice. But often, there are multiple producers and consumers.